# Having trouble updating ImageIcon within java weather gui app

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, rss

I am attempting to create a simple gui weather app, that consumes the BBC rss weather feed, and displays certain information on the weather stored in the xml file passed to the app via a url.

I have succeeded in consuming and parsing the rss feed, and then displaying the weather information within the GUI, however am now trying to implement weather icons that summarise the weather description.

In my weatherParser class I have written an iconChecker method that uses a switch case statement, to change the icon depending on the weatherCode variable.

The weatherCode is determined through a series of if-else statements from within my weatherGUI class, where I then call the iconChecker method passing the weather code and label as parameters.

However when i run the gui, the weather data is outputted to the gui after supplying a url and clicking the forecast button, but I do not see any icons. I'm not sure if it is a simple fix or whether I am on completely the wrong lines, therefore any help would be much appreciated.

iconChecker method code:

```
 /**
 *  Case switch checks for weather description and selects relevant
 * icon to display
 * @param weatherCode - each code refers to a different weather state
 * @param label - the JLabel to update with relevant icon.
 */
public void iconChecker(int weatherCode, JLabel label) {

    switch (weatherCode) {

        case 1: ImageIcon veryHot = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/veryHot.png");
                label.setIcon(veryHot);
                break;
        case 2: ImageIcon cloudyDay = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/rain.png");
                label.setIcon(cloudyDay);
                break;
        case 3: ImageIcon night = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/snow.png");
                label.setIcon(night);
                break;
        case 4: ImageIcon snowy = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/cloudyDay.png");
                label.setIcon(snowy);
                break;
        case 5: ImageIcon storm = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/night.png");
                label.setIcon(storm);
                break;
        case 6: ImageIcon rain = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/storm.png");
                label.setIcon(rain);
                break;         

    }  

}
```

forecastButton actionPerformed method code:

```
private void forecastButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               


    String url = urlField.getText();    
    int weathercode = 0;

    CharSequence sun = "sunny";
    CharSequence rain = "rain";
    CharSequence snow = "snow";
    CharSequence cloud = "cloud";
    CharSequence night = "night";
    CharSequence storm = "storm";

    try {
        WeatherParser parser = new WeatherParser();
        URL u = new URL(url);
        weather = parser.parse(u); 
        reportBox.setText(weather);

        // Each weather description is associated with a weather code
        if (weather.contains(sun)) {           
            weathercode = 1;
        }
        else if (weather.contains(rain)) {
            weathercode = 2;
        }
        else if (weather.contains(snow)) {
            weathercode = 3;
        }
        else if (weather.contains(cloud)) {
            weathercode = 4;
        }
        else if (weather.contains(night)) {
            weathercode = 5;
        }
        else if (weather.contains(storm)) {
            weathercode = 6;
        }
        else {
            weathercode = 0;
        }


        // Call iconChecker method to update label with relevant icon.
        parser.iconChecker(weathercode, iconLabel);


    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException | MalformedURLException |
            SAXException | XPathException | NullPointerException ex) {}
    catch (IOException ex) {}        


}
```

Comment: Code looks reasonable. Did you verify the proper case statement is executed? Did you verify the Icon is read correctly? Don't use empty catch blocks.

Comment: @camickr i just altered the code slightly to print out to the console when a case was selected, however nothing printed, therefore I am assuming the problem lies in my switch case statement, however still can not figure out what it is.

Comment: Did you print out the value of the `weathcode` variable? Did you print out the value of the `weather` variable? We can't debug your code for you. Only you have the actual data that you are testing.